# MYSQL error on cmd pasting

Tags: mysql

I am on a mac system . I have mysql installed . I wanted to create a table in a database named ticket_system

```
create table ticket_system.Train
(
    Train_no            NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name                char(10),
    source              char(10),
    destination         char(10),
    start_time          DATE,
    reach_time          DATE,
    traveltime          NUMBER(10),
    distance            NUMBER(10), 
    class               NUMBER(10),
    days                NUMBER(10),
    type                char(10)
    );
```

I wrote the code in sublime for connivence. And then tried pasting in the terminal. I get this error

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY, Name char(10), source char(10), destination char(10), st' at line 1

it seem like my code somehow ended after st which was supposed to be start_time.

On pasting I was asked by iterm2 that there are tabs and how would you like to treat them as and I selected 4 spaces which was default.

What can be the reason for this error and what is the best method to practise mysql for my exam? Please let me know the alternatives also if this is not a convenient way.

Comment: MySQL has no  `number` data type. Use `int`

Comment: `NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY ...` is mentioned in the error message. That is the place to look at and not at the end of the error message. MySQL just cuts off the rest because it is irrelevant.

Comment: My college taught me NUMBER which was working in mysql plus . INT worked thanks a lot :)

Comment: @juergend please mark your answer as the final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not have a `number()` data type. Use `INT` or a [similar data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) which is appropriate for auto incrementation.

If you need a fixed-point data type for numbers like `13.98` then use `numeric()`.